# Debian boot to single-user mode

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I forgot my root password and am attempting to change it by booting into single-user mode, however when booting I get this screen:

[image]

Then I press "e" to edit the boot configuration and I get this screen:

[image]

However, in the tutorial I'm following it says I should navigate to the line that starts with "kernel", but as you can see, I dont have this line.
So I tried changing "quiet" to "single" on the line that starts with "linux /boot/vmlinuz...." but this doesn't boots the system into single-user mode.

What line am I supposed to edit in order for this to work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One method:

1. Append `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the grub line which begins with `linux` (and ends with `quiet`).
2. Reset your password and reboot normally.
3. Don't forget it again.
4. Consider installing `sudo`.

---

Another method:

1. Since this is apparently a virtual machine, you can mount its disk on another (working) virtual machine and manually remove the password from the `/etc/shadow` file. Or use `kpartx` to work with the virtual machine image file from the host or from another machine.

Comment: Now it shows me "root@(none)#" though and it doesn't know any commands, how do I fix that?

Comment: You probably don't have a `PATH`. Try calling `/usr/bin/passwd` (or anything else) directly. Or just look around and see what you have available to you.

Comment: using `/bin/bash` as init won't call any of the startup scripts to mount partitions, etc. either so if you have `/usr` in a separate partition you'll need to mount it by hand.  Also know that you won't get the shutdown scripts either, when bash exits the kernel will immediately halt.  Be sure to sync the drives first or changes may not be written.

Answer (score 24):

DEBIAN / UBUNTU root PASSWORD RECOVERY

1. First screen - grub - press <kbd>e</kbd>
2. Modify kernel line: add `single` between `ro  quiet` and at the end of this line add `init=/bin/bash`
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd>
4. When the prompt is `root@(none):/#` you have to remount the / partition to have read-write access:
   `mount / -rw -o remount`
5. Now you are ready to modify the root password: type `passwd` and change it!

Good luck

P.S: try to look at the /etc/shadow file to find other users...

Comment: This was the right answer for me, with the `mount` command. Thanks.

Comment: You may also want to, instead of remounting `/` as `rw`, just change the `ro` in the `kernel` line to just read `rw`.

Answer (score 1):

Your tutorial refers to Grub (legacy Grub). This is Grub2. The line beginning with linux would be the kernel line in Grub.

Comment: I don't have a tutorial written anywhere, this was an old question of mine

Answer (score -1):

wooo, just choose the recovery mode dude, you'll be switch to a BusyBox without any kind of password (normally).

Comment: Just tried it, also asks for a login after booting, during the boot I get the same maintenance question asking me for the root password or to press ctrl+D to continue

Comment: did you press Ctrl+D ? I already had such reaction on some linux tweaked box, and a Ctrl+D did the trick.

Comment: yes I did, but then it just resumes like a normal boot and asks for the login

Comment: @DrI Debian's default is to require the root password for single user mode.

Comment: Hum... are you sure?? I just installed a fresh Inet 6.0.6 version using default values for the setup and my single mode is NOT requiring any password.

Comment: I tested with debian 9, recovery menu item without modifications DO require a root password.