# Apparent lockup during attempt to recover root password

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, password-recovery

I have a computer running Debian Jessie, and need to recover my root password. I've been following the instructions on [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/482079/398788), but have run into a snag. After GRUB loads and I've appended `single init=/bin/bash` to the appropriate line and rebooted, the system appears to lock up - or at least does not accept any input from my keyboard. I don't appear to be at a proper command prompt, so I'm guessing the former is true.

What can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: If it helps, bash reports the following before my computer stops responding: `cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device` followed by `no job control in this shell`

Comment: You are not meant to mix `single` and `init=` on the same kernel command line. Try again without `single`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Got things figured out between this and my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough the problem seems to have stemmed from my keyboard. When I switched to an older, simpler keyboard the command prompt took input as expected. I also removed `single` per Michael's comment on my question.

Comment: For the curious: the offending keyboard is a 'Microsoft Digital Media Keyboard 3000'. No clue if that's enough to duplicate the problem, however.